# Get WCF request parameters in UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: wcf, authentication, custom-authentication

I have a stateless server with an WCF service. The server can have several DB connections. Therefore I must give the DB connection for EACH WCF request. I do this within a request object. So every WCF request to my server contains information about the DB connection.
This is the operation contract for the function:

```
 <OperationContract()>
 Function ReadPersons(ByVal aRequest As ReadPersonsRequest) As PersonsResponse
```

This is the data contract for the request:

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class ReadPersonsRequest
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property DatabaseConfig() As DatabaseConfig
```

Now I want a custom authentication for my WCF service. Therefore I implemented a CustomUserNamePasswordValidator inherited from UserNamePasswordValidator. I get the username and the password. The users are stored in the DB. Therefore I must do a DB request for the authentication. The problem is: I do not know which DB the server should use, because this information is submitted in the request object of the WCF service function (see above).

Is there any way to get the parameter (the request object) of the called WCF service function in the implementation of the UserNamePasswordValidator?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `MessageInspectors` so that you can intercept the request before it is received at the server. In this way you can identify the database details from the service call and proceed accordingly.

More details on the implementation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest.aspx)